# Conditional probability and relationship to conditional expectation

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

It is well-known that $$\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}]$$

for an event $A \in \Omega$.

However, if we have a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ then it certainly it is not true that $$\mathbb{P}(A|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{A}|\mathcal{F}]$$

since the LHS is a real number, while the RHS is a function.

My question is: Do we have a similar relationship between conditional probability (on a $\sigma$-algebra) and the expectation of an indicator function?

Comment: You wrote LHS twice "since the LHS is a real number, while the LHS is a function."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LHS is NOT a number; you can check Durrett Probability Theory and Examples that the second equality is actually correct. (version 4.1, page 191 at the end).

The way that people sometimes use $\mathbb{P}(A \mid B)$ is simply the value of this random variable on the event B, i.e. then it becomes a number.

Comment: So then $E[P(A|\mathcal{F})]=P(A)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly indeed.

Comment: Doesn't the value of $P(A|\sigma(1_B))$ depend on further information, but $P(A|B)$ does not and is fixed? $P(A|\sigma(1_B))=P(A|\{\emptyset,B,B^c,\Omega\})$ can equal several values, including $P(A|B)$ or $P(A|B^c)$, yes?

Comment: Right, so P(A | B) is somewhat of an abuse of a notation in my opinion; you are essentially evaluating P(A | $\sigma(1_B)$) on the set B.

Comment: @E-A, thanks for the verification. It was just a bit unclear from your answer, a slight edit might help.