# Conditional probability (on event) as conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Related to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781111/conditional-probability-and-relationship-to-conditional-expectation), how do we write the following conditional probability for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ conditioned on an event occurring (such as $\mathrm{P}[X > x \mid X>Y]$) as a conditional expectation?
It seems that conditioning on the event $\{X>Y\}$ seems to be an abuse of notation per the linked question.

So I'm wondering if this is correct:
$$
\mathrm{P}[X > x \mid X>Y] = \mathrm{E}[ 1_{\{X>x\}} \mid X > Y] = \int 1_{\{X>x\}} \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\mathrm{P}[X>Y]} dx dy
$$
or do I need to integrate against the conditional density $f_{X \mid Y}(x,y)$ instead? If so, I don't see how to get $f_{X \mid Y}(x,y)$.

Comment: Try not to use densities in your proofs. Not all random variables have densities.

Comment: Ah thanks. Supposing that they are continuous, is this the right way to think about it? Your answer indicates no, but I am missing something I think

Comment: You have to integrate over the set $x>y$: $\iint_{x>y} ...dxdy$.

Comment: @dunno However, **never** use the same token as both a free variable *and* an integral's bound variable.  You have $x$ as a free variable in $\mathsf P(X>x\mid X>Y)$ so it *must* not occur as the integral's bound variable (use a fresh token).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition: $$\mathsf P(X>x\mid X>Y)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X>\max\{x,Y\})}{\mathsf P(X>Y)}\\\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{\small X>x}\mid X>Y)=\dfrac{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{\small X>\max\{x,Y\}})}{\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{\small X>Y})}\quad$$

So, *when* $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables with joint density function $f_{\small X,Y}$, *then* :$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>x\mid X>Y)&=\dfrac{\iint_{s>\max\{x,t\}}f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d \langle s,t\rangle}{\iint_{s>t}f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d \langle s,t\rangle}\\[3ex]&=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^x\int_x^\infty f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t+\int_{x}^\infty\int_{t}^\infty f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_t^\infty f_{\small X,Y}(s,t)\,\mathrm d s\,\mathrm d t}\end{align}$$

---

Note: Do **not** use the same token, $x$, as *both* a free variable *and* the integral's bound variable.    Always use *fresh* tokens as an integrals bound variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the general definition of conditional expectation $P(X >x|X>Y)$ is  a random variable which takes the value $\frac {P(X >x, X>Y)} {P(X>Y)}$ on the set $\{X>Y\}$ and the value $\frac {P(X >x, X\leq Y)} {P(X\leq Y)}$ on the set $\{ X \leq Y\}$.